# Why does Visual Studio show multiple threads even though my MFC app isn't multithreaded?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a single-threaded MFC SDI application. When I run it in Visual Studio, the output window shows **2** threads exiting instead of one. It does this for both debug and release builds. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows itself starts threads in order to perform work on behalf of your code.  Other components like GDI+ and Sockets do the same thing.  There's more to your process than just the code that you wrote!

Comment: Oh, and Visual Studio will show them even though I don't control their code base?

Comment: @aguazales: Yes, because they belong to your process.  The debugger shows you everything, not just the code you write.